# Visual studio - is there a way to select multiple files and wrap a namespace around each of them?

Tags: visual-studio, automation, namespaces

Is there a way to select all classes within a folder and assign a namespace to each of them  in visual studio?

If there is no tool to do it, is there a regex pattern that will match everything before the class declatarion, but after the imports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Resharper has a feature of changing namespaces](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/documentation/help20/Refactoring/renaming.html) for files.

For a manual solution, you could:

- close all files in your solution
- open only those files who need their namespace changed
- perform a find-and-replace for `namespace old` to `namespace new`